# How do wizards cast spells which appear on their spell list when it has a divine focus component?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, spell-components

What does a wizard do to cast a spell which contains a DF component?

Take [magic weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-weapon) for example,

> Components V, S, DF

[Divine Focus (DF)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Components)

> A divine focus component is an item of spiritual significance. The divine focus for a cleric or a paladin is a holy symbol appropriate to the character's faith. The divine focus for a druid or a ranger is a sprig of holly, or some other sacred plant.
>
> If the Components line includes F/DF or M/DF, the arcane version of the spell has a focus component or a material component (the abbreviation before the slash) and the divine version has a divine focus component (the abbreviation after the slash).

So do wizards have holy/unholy symbols in their spell components pouch or what?

Answer (score 11):

## Wizards ignore all divine focus requirements.

Often, the requirement is "M/DF", in which case "M" part is for arcane spellcasters, and "DF" part is for divine spellcasters. One example of these requirements is *greater* magic weapon spell. Arcane version of "regular" magic weapon spell has only verbal and somatic components.

Comment: I'll add (to both answers, really) that Oracles don't need to have a Divine Focus for spells requiring one.

Answer (score 5):

## **No**

You don't need a divine focus as a wizard. Divine focuses are meant for divine spells only. Sadly RAW doesn't seem to address this. It is however strongly implied by the definition of a [Divine Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Components)

> The divine focus for a cleric or a paladin is a holy symbol appropriate to the character's faith. The divine focus for a druid or a ranger is a sprig of holly, or some other sacred plant.

This definition states what counts as a divine focus for these classes. Wizards are not mentioned, in fact only divine spell casters are mentioned.
Thus by RAW wizard don't even have a way of supplying a divine focus for a spell.