# Can an arcane caster cast a spell that has as its only focus component a divine focus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, spell-components

[Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/) on [Components](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Components) on **Divine Focus (DF)** says

> A divine focus component is an item of spiritual significance. The divine focus for a cleric or a paladin is a holy symbol appropriate to the character’s faith. The divine focus for a druid or a ranger is a sprig of holly, or some other sacred plant.
>
> If the Components line includes F/DF or M/DF, the arcane version of the spell has a focus component or a material component (the abbreviation before the slash) and the divine version has a divine focus component (the abbreviation after the slash).

However, rather than having a *Components* entry of F/DF or M/DF, some spells have *only* a DF entry. For example, the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spells [*magic weapon*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-weapon)  and [*stone shield*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/stone-shield/) have DF entries rather than F/DF or M/DF entries.

Besides extrapolating from or assuming based on the text quoted above, do the rules elsewhere actually say whether or not an arcane caster can (or must) satisfy this standalone DF-only component?

---

***Note:** A similar question is asked [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89942/how-do-wizards-cast-spells-which-appear-on-their-spell-list-when-it-has-a-divine).*

Comment: @Adeptus I linked to that in my post but it didn't cite any evidence.

Comment: That's an issue with the answers, not the question

Comment: @Adeptus a question doesn't answer a question last I checked.

Comment: @MageintheBarrel a duplicate is to mark an question that will get the same response. The answers in the duplicate (should) answer your question.

Comment: @Ben I’m asking for citation since neither of those answers has citations it doesn’t answer my question. It’s also not RAW if it’s not written down and until I see it written down I will not consider something RAW.

Comment: @Ben since it’s closed even though my question wasn’t answered I’ll go ask elsewhere.

Comment: I'd probably put more emphasis on the request for citation

Comment: All answers should ideally be cited. The quality of the answers to the linked question - specifically whether they have citations or not - doesn't affect whether or not the question is a duplicate. If it is the same question but you're simply unsatisfied with the answers to the linked question, you can comment on relevant answers to request citations, or add a bounty to the linked question to request better references (there's even a specific bounty reason you can choose for this: "Authoritative reference needed - Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.").

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing bounties were made for. Put a bounty on the other one asking for cited sources.

Comment: @V2Blast I wasn’t aware that you can place bounties on other people’s questions. I’ll do that.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I’m looking for a credible source that tells me yes or no such as the faq or an official book. Not just the obvious ones like “it doesn’t say so you can’t” or “it was obviously their intention to make it so they just didn’t include it.”

Comment: @williamporter see my reply to V2Blast

Comment: @HeyICanChan once I’m home from work

Comment: @HeyICanChan thanks